# Using Apache Ignite for ACID Transactions In Apache Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, ignite

I would like to know whether we can achieve traditional ACID Transactions(like in RDBMS)if we use Apache Ignite with Cassandra, or is it just limited by the use cases mentioned in this link:  https://www.gridgain.com/technology/integrations/apache-cassandra ?

My Idea: use Ignite to cache the required rows from Cassandra , do the process(like U,D operations) and the update the DBs.[Assumption: Using one ignite node mapped to a cluster of C* nodes]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cassandra does not have transactional support. Ignite, however, does allow to execute ACID transactions consistently with the persistent store, in case the latter has support for this. Take a look at example [1] that demonstrates such integration with a typical relational DB.

[1] https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/datagrid/store/jdbc/CacheJdbcStoreExample.java